# Rails/General SQL entity-attribute-value for complex schema

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I'm having some trouble coming up with an effective database model for a set of complex relations and wondering if my current implementation will work well.

I'm working with location-specific data, in this case city permits, storing the permit requirements, and relating them to specific locations. Because there are many cities, and the permit requirements differ from city to city, I'm struggling to find the best way to record a specific location's progress with permit requirements.

Currently, my schema looks like:

```
<permit>
id
type
state
```

```
<requirements>
id
key
value
```

```
<permit_requirements>
permit_id
requirement_id
```

This works fine for storing all of the permit requirements, and recalling them. The issue is when relating them to specific locations. Currently I have:

```
<location>
id
state
```

```
<location_permits>
permit_id
location_id
```

And this works fine for returning all permits (filtered by state) and the children requirements. But to store the status of specific requirements, I'm thinking:

```
<location_requirement_answers>
location_id
requirement_id
status
```

Does this make sense? Is this an anti-pattern? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the best way to pull in permits as a whole, and specific statuses per location.

I'm thinking that the related permits create the base list, and then on changes I would update the `location_requirements_answer` specifically. But would this require another relation for `location_permits`, i.e. `location_permit_answers` that would basically duplicate the original relation except with the answered requirements?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? Is there a person or company in place who needs to request this city permit? Or is it from the state itself?

Comment: Of course @double_u1! There is no specific request needed, they just come from the state and an admin uploads the requirements. For example, there could be a permit with `type` "fire" and _x_ number of requirements, i.e. requirement with `key` "6' of defensible space." The part I'm having trouble with is that after permits + requirements are in the database, then any number of users can mark specific requirements as complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still having trouble wrapping my head around this, but here's what seems to work for now (albeit with performance concerns with too many database queries that definitely won't scale):

1. Remove
   <s>`<location_permits>`</s>
2. Add `permits` attribute to `location` and filter by state, this pulls in nested `requirements` as well
3. Query `location_requirements_answers` with the returned `requirement_id`